# VBA: Using Defined Name Feature in AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba

VBA newbie here. Hoping for your patience.

**My goal:** Autofilter but filters are in an editable table to easily adjust filters. Hence, I utilized Defined Names in my code.

**The Defined Names:**

1. ShName - Name of Worksheet
2. Col 1 - Column Number
3. Filter 1 - First Filter, such that I aim for the filter to also be in Array form, i.e., instead of having to manually modify my code to Criteria:= Array(Range().Value), I can simply put Criteria:= Range().Value

**TheTable**

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Col. | Filter |
| 2 | 1 *(Col1)* | One Value *(Filter1)* |
| 3 | 2 *(Col2)* | (Value1, Value2, Value3) *(Filter2)* |

*B3 refers to 1 filter only, while B3 refers to Array

**My code:**

```
Sub filter()
Worksheets(Range("ShName").Value).Activate

If IsEmpty(Range("Col 1").Value) = True Then 
   Go To Done
   Else: ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=Range("Col1").Value, Criteria:=Range("Filter1"), Operator:= xlFilterValues 'Error starts to pop up
End If

If IsEmpty(Range("Col 2").Value) = True Then 
   Go To Done
   Else: ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=Range("Col2").Value, Criteria:=Range("Filter2"), Operator:= xlFilterValues
End If

Done:

End Sub
```

**My issue:** Error pops up as soon as I call the Defined Names in AutoFilter

Your help is appreciated thank you

Comment: Missing a closing quote, `Criteria:=Range("Filter1), ` --> `Criteria:=Range("Filter1"), `

Comment: Typo in the question, edited it now

Comment: It would help if you provided the exact error message too.

Comment: I'm not too sure but instead of doing `Else:` on one line, put the `Else` code in its own proper block...That `:` might be confusing things too...?  Why not also try `If IsEmpty() = False Then` and you can avoid having to use `GoTo`

Comment: Code such as " if IsEmpty(Range("Col 1").Value) = True" is more correctly written as "if IsEmpty(Range("Col 1").Value)" because the function returns True or False so no need to check against true (or false)

Comment: You can also replace your Goto Done with Exit Function.  If you are new to VBA then you should install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA which amongst many other things does a stricter static analysis of VBA code.  You will learn how to write more correct VBA code if you pay attention to the code inspections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure to use a valid name for your named range. Names like "Col 1" and "Col1" are not valid, while `Col_1` is an acceptable option.
- Additionally, consider using `Exit Sub` instead of `Goto` to improve the readability and maintainability of your code.
- Input `Value1,Value2,Value3` (w/o
  parentheses and space) as `Filter2`, it's easy to generate an array  with `Split` function for the 2nd filter.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyFilter()

    Dim oRng As Range
    Worksheets(Range("ShName").Value).Activate
    Set oRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    
    If IsEmpty(Range("Col_1").Value) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        oRng.AutoFilter Field:=Range("Col_1").Value, Criteria1:=Range("Filter1")
    End If
    
    If IsEmpty(Range("Col_2").Value) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        oRng.AutoFilter Field:=Range("Col_2").Value, _
        Criteria1:=Split(Range("Filter2"), ","), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [AutoFilter object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

btw, By organizing the cells in the below suggested layout, it will be more convenient to create and manage the defined names in your workbook.

[image]

Comment: Hi Taller, thanks much for this! However, I don't think the Array part is working. For context, the column where I'll be filtering includes cells in Formula Form. I tried putting it in Paste Values but still, the Array code did not capture the filters I needed. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `if the column to search from is in Formula form` in OP or comment.

Comment: For example, my search Column is Column G. My filter is (111-111, 111-112, 111-113).

Values: G2= (in Formula form) -> =A2&B2 , G3 = "111-111", G4 = "111-112".

G3 and G4 are in PasteValue form. While G2 is in FormulaForm.

Comment: ^ For both PasteValue Form and Formula Form, the Split(Range("Filter2"), ",") does not work :<

Comment: In OP, the filter2 is a list in a cell. Looks like it is changed now. Is range G2:G3 named as `Filter2` in the given example?

Comment: Hi Taller, please nevermind, I already found a workaround thank you! :D

Comment: Hi Taller, if you don't mind, what if instead of (Value1, Value2, Value3), there are spaces within the string, i.e.  (Value 1, Value 2, Value 3). Seems Operator:=xlFilterValues does not work? Thank you

Comment: `(  )` in cell doesn't make it be an array when the code read cell value. If you prefer to use it,  you have to revise the code to remove it before apply the 2nd filter.